# how to redirect to edited page after saving record through $A.get("e.force:editRecord")

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using  `$A.get("e.force:editRecord")` to edit a record and after editing a record successfully, it should redirect to the edited record.
But it remains in same record. Any help will be appreciated.

```
editRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": component.get("v.contact.Id")
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

if i am using above code, i am unable to redirect to edited record.

Comment: Can you please post the code you already have? This way others can make better suggestions.

Comment: Any suggestions on this?